# Inconsistent look of Text Input in react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

[This is screenshot of my app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0jPP.jpg)This is regarding React Native Mobile App Development.

I am using "Text Input" in React Native.

While running the App on Android Phones the UI components are looking consistent.

But running on iPhone it becomes consistent and the "Labels" for Text Input fields becomes very small & loose all the styles & margins between fields.

Please find attached the Android & iPhone images.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't feel like handling the styling difference between Android & iOS by yourself, i would advise you to use [react-native-elements](https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/)

It allows you to implement design that would remain reliable between both OS.
It is also highly customizable

Hope it helps ;)